# Drop down div with 3D sliding animation?

Tags: jquery, css

anybody knows the technique in creating a menu like the one on http://cube.rallyinteractive.com/

I am currently using jquery slide toggle but I want to add more css animation to it like the one above.

Thanks

Comment: That example uses CSS 3D transforms. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try doing it with **CSS3** `transform` property? check out the link, and let me know if it was helpful, cheers.

[Cube](http://codepen.io/hmps/pen/LBmDl)

Comment: Well, yes it does, but considering the responsiveness, you may wanna manipulate some piece of code in order to align objects well in all the screen sizes....